# determine the user on SharePoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint

How can I know the user logging onto SharePoint through code?
I am using WebPart inside it SmartPart and inside it a User control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the user informations with :

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser
```

Here are some informations like email, ID, Groups, Name...
Type Ctrl + Space ;)

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your SharePoint site is running under Windows Authentication (which most would be).  In that case you can get the current user name using:

```
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
string username = context.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: You can directly access to the SharePoint HttpContext with SPContext :)